# How to Send File to printer Directly Through Code in asp.net c# when web Application host on local server

Tags: c#

This Code will work when code run from visual studio.
But Not work when host on local host. not call to printer.

```
    protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            objBel.BillId = lblbillid.Text;
            objBel.NetAmount = txtnetbillamt.Text;
            objBel.PDiscount = txtdiscountpercentage.Text;
            objBel.DiscountA = txtdiscountamount.Text;
            objBel.TaxAmt = txttaxamount.Text;
            objBel.PaymentMode = ddlpaymentMode.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (ddlpaymentMode.SelectedItem.Text == "Cheque")
            {
                objBel.ChequeNo = txtchno.Text;
                if (txtDate.SelectedDate != null)
                {
                    objBel.ChequeDate = txtDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                }
                objBel.ChequeDetails = txtotherdetails.Text;
            }
            if (rbyes.Checked)
            {
                objBel.ThirdParty = txtthirdpartydiscription.Text;
            }
            objBel.FinalAmt = txtfinalamount.Text;
            objBel.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
            objBel.Time = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm tt");
            int i = objBal.UpdateBill(objBel);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                Session["Billid"] = "";           
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = objBal.BillGenrate(lblbillid.Text);
                ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
                doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport/BillPrint.rpt"));
                doc.SetDataSource(dt);
                if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\Billprints\\Invoice.txt")))
                    File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\Billprints\\Invoice.txt"));
                string fileName = Server.MapPath("\\Billprints\\") + "Invoice.txt";
                doc.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Text, fileName);
                doc.Refresh();
                doc.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);


            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Error Occur Try Again !!')", true);

            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: What are the parameters in PrintToPrinter?  Do they refer to the index number of the installed printers?  The printers on different PCs are not installed necessarily in the same order.

Comment: You are aware that this will print to a printer installed and configured on the server, rather than any associated with the machine that the browser is running on, aren't you?